# Когда и как включается DI в asp netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

В описаниях DI для asp netcore пишут, что настройка выполняется в ConfigureServices() класса Startup.

Но как тогда уже в конструкторе (!!!) этого класса можно передавать параметр IConfiguration выходит DI включается еще раньше?

В пустом проекте класс выглядит так:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
```

но в некоторых вопросах вижу, что можно передать еще другие параметры:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
```

Где же тогда происходт настройка этого и что можно еще передать на конструктор?

Смотрел в Program.cs но там пусто:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    private static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Это всё делается внутри CreateDefaultBuilder, там написано (упрощённо) следующее:

Создаётся билдер и настраиваются параметры args из командной строки (если есть):

```
  WebHostBuilder hostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder();

  if (args != null)
    hostBuilder.UseConfiguration((IConfiguration) new ConfigurationBuilder().AddCommandLine(args).Build());
```

Потом включается веб-сервер Kestrel и у него сразу устанавливается IHostingEnvironment, настраивается логирование, первые сервисы  (и потому вы можете использовать это всё в своём Startup.cs) и включается поддержка IIS.

```
    hostBuilder.UseKestrel( ...
      {
        IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
      })).ConfigureLogging( ...
      {
        logging.AddConfiguration(
        logging.AddConsole();
        logging.AddDebug();
        logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
      })).ConfigureServices( ...      
      }))
      .UseIIS().UseIISIntegration().UseDefaultServiceProvider();

      return (IWebHostBuilder) hostBuilder;
```

Всё остальное это уже потом вы сами включаете в Startup.cs по потребности (например, DbContext и т.п. вещи)

> и что можно еще передать на конструктор

Судя [по документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.2) можно три вещи:

- IHostingEnvironment
- IConfiguration
- ILoggerFactory

Лично мне кроме штатного IConfiguration только однажды пришлось писать [собственный провайдер](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/2.15.php) конфигурации, а примеры на логирование я только синтетические писал на обучении.